# Download Excel vba code from module with Sub name

Tags: excel, vba, module

I have more than 40 mdoules scattered on my PERSONAL.XLSB file. I would like to download all the 40 modules including sub name. Is there a way to download it with/without code?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear - Instead of "Download", do you perhaps mean "Export to files"?

Comment: See [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) for how to program the VBE.

Answer (score 1):

If as Blackhawk asks you mean Export To files then here is some code...

```
'* requires Tools->Reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3"
Sub T()
    Dim prj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Set prj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

    Dim oLoop As VBIDE.VBComponent
    For Each oLoop In prj.VBComponents

        If oLoop.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule Then
            Dim sFileName As String
            sFileName = "c:\temp\" & oLoop.Name & ".bas"
            Debug.Print sFileName
            oLoop.Export sFileName
        End If

    Next oLoop

End Sub
```

If you can't find necessary Tools Reference then try this which does not require it, this is late-bound code...

```
Sub T()
    Dim prj As Object 'VBIDE.VBProject
    Set prj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

    Dim oLoop As Object 'VBIDE.VBComponent
    For Each oLoop In prj.VBComponents

        If oLoop.Type = 1 Then  'vbext_ct_StdModule=1
            Dim sFileName As String
            sFileName = "c:\temp\" & oLoop.Name & ".bas"
            Debug.Print sFileName
            oLoop.Export sFileName
        End If

    Next oLoop

End Sub
```